# Node.JS MySql Waiting for expected result in Loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a loop in Node.js with mysql for the Discordbot that waits until the result of the mysql matches what I want, but all I get is this error:
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
TypeError: Cannot read property 'day' of undefined

MySql connection and everything else works. But when he didn't find a result, I got this error and my bot crashed.

My Code:

```
  var requestloop = setInterval(function(){
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.IP,
      user: process.env.US,
      password: process.env.PW,
      database: "XYZ"
    });

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT name,day FROM team WHERE day='0:45'", function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;

      //Sending Congrats
      if (result[0].day == "0:45")
        {    
          let Worktime = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(result[0].name + `, Congratulations, you've finished work for today`)
          .setColor("GREEN");
          client.channels.cache.get('702139096683905054').send(Worktime);
          con.end();
        }
        else
        {
          return con.end();
        }
      });
    });
  }, 60000); //1 Minute
```

Comment: Can you console.log(result)?

Comment: @Cursed there is no result I can log, that's the problem xD. I want the code to ignore the error and just return. And then try again in 1 minute if it gets a result now.

Comment: if(result? result[0].day : "0:44" == "0:45") try this if no result the string will be 44 and just go to else

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately I still get the error 'day' of undefined

Comment: Okay now i got a result => [ RowDataPacket { day: '0:47' } ] <= In the Console. But after this i got the error again Cannot read property 'day' of undefined.

Comment: change result[0].day to result.day

Comment: Thanks .... I Hate javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(result? result.day : "0:44" == "0:45")
```

try this if no result the string will be 44 and just go to else